# Is there a jQuery solution that uses CORS when available and falls back to XDomainRequest on MSIE and JSONP on browsers with niether?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-domain, jsonp, cors

I was silly enough to believe that all modern browsers supported [`CORS` (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

When my toy JavaScript tool didn't work on IE9 or Opera I found out that the former only supported `CORS` through `XDomainRequest`, which jQuery doesn't seem to support. Opera doesn't support `CORS` at all yet.

Now jQuery has an abstract interface that does normal same domain AJAX queries, `CORS` queries, and even `JSONP` queries the same way.

Is there an extension to this interface that goes further making it work even with `XDomainRequest` and falling back to `JSONP` when `CORS` isn't available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a plugin for XDomainRequest support in JQuery:

https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js

There is also a jQuery feature request to add this feature:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283

Note that the bug report says that there may be an issue with the plugin in IE9, so YMMV. It ended up getting closed with the reason given that the plugin exists to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [xReader](http://kincrew.github.com/xReader/):

```
<script src="http://kincrew.github.com/xReader/xReader.full.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
xReader("http://www.yahoo.com/", function(data) { 
    alert(data.content); 
})
</script>
```

It's simple!

Comment: I like xReader after having a quick play with it. But after using it to read the number of google hits for a search term half a dozen times Google automatically blocked it. If Google can I guess other sites could too.

Comment: @hippietrail , I want check that. Could you tell me which url was used.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with some code. It should work the first few times you try it then you'll start getting `null` for Google: http://jsfiddle.net/hippietrail/fS6n2/2/

Comment: @hippietrail I'd fix in a few days. It seems xReader have to handle more detail info like ua. (Referer, UA Info, Cookies)

Comment: The Example for Wall St Journal also returns undefined.