# JS CORS issue with IE - how to resolve?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, getjson, cors

I know this has been visited a lot, and I have managed to get this working with other projects.  I have inherited this chunk of code that does not work in IE:

```
function loadTemplate(template, alt_cache_name) {
    if (templates[template] !== undefined) {
        if (alt_cache_name !== undefined) {
            templates[alt_cache_name] = templates[template];
        }
        return templates[template];
    } else {

        return $.get(template, function (response) {
            if (alt_cache_name !== undefined) {
                templates[alt_cache_name] = response;
            }
            templates[template] = response;
        }, 'text');
    }
}
```

The issue is with the $.get().

The value of `template` is a url to a specific html template.

I tried the following, but I don't think the return type is the same as what was returned from $.get():

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}


function loadTemplate(template, alt_cache_name) {
    if (templates[template] !== undefined) {
        if (alt_cache_name !== undefined) {
            templates[alt_cache_name] = templates[template];
        }
        return templates[template];
    } else {

        var request = createCORSRequest("GET", template);
        var content = "";
        if (request) {
            request.onload = function () {
                //do something with request.responseText
                console.log(request.responseText);
                if (alt_cache_name !== undefined) {
                    templates[alt_cache_name] = response.responseText;
                }
                templates[template] = response.responseText;
            };
        }

        return request;


        //            return $.get(template, function (response) {
        //                if (alt_cache_name !== undefined) {
        //                    templates[alt_cache_name] = response;
        //                }
        //                templates[template] = response;
        //            }, 'text');
    }
}
```

I even tried the `$.get` with:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Can someone shed some light on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the jQuery plugin listed [here](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js) did the trick.  Upon further reading, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688703/is-there-a-jquery-solution-that-uses-cors-when-available-and-falls-back-to-xdoma) also detailed the solution.

-- UPDATE --

Upon further testing there seems to be some issue with IE9 and this library.  Any one else experience any issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was unable to load templates from a CDN at runtime using CORS on IE 8/9. I was able to get it working by including the xhr-xdr-adapter.js file from here: https://github.com/intuit/xhr-xdr-adapter/blob/master/src/xhr-xdr-adapter.js

You can include it where needed as follows:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script src="xhr-xdr-adapter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The xhr-xdr-adapter replaces XMLHttpRequest with a different function, which figures out at run time whether to use the native XMLHttpRequest or the XDomainRequest instead.  By including it, I've been able to do cross-domain loading of templates, both with jQuery and AngularJS.