# $.get not working in IE when using CORS headers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cors

I go to the [jquery $.get documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) from my vbox Windows XP installation in Forefox. Then press F12 for firebug console and paste the following code to run:

```
$.get("http://10.0.2.2/info.php"
 ,null,function(data){console.log(data);}
).fail(function(e){console.log("ERROR:"+e.statusText);})
```

10.0.2.2/info.php points to the following php file on my computer:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo "howdie";
?>
```

This works correctly in Firefox and displays "howdie". However when opening IE 8 go to the [$.get documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), pressing F12, going to script tag and executing the same code I get:

> ERROR: No Transport

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery solution that uses CORS when available and falls back to XDomainRequest on MSIE and JSONP on browsers with niether?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688703/is-there-a-jquery-solution-that-uses-cors-when-available-and-falls-back-to-xdoma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference; I solved it as [jQuery $.AJAX does not support CORS](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) and you have to write your own transport to support this. (and then linking to a dead link)

This is because jQuery uses an XMLHttpRequest object when it's available but IE 8 and 9 XMLHttpRequest do not support CORS headers and need a XDomainRequest. I consider this a bug in jQuery.

Two years ago this was [submitted to the jQuery team](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) by someone who considered it a bug as well and then ignored. Even though implementing the cors header should be supported by xhr requests they decided not to.

I fully agree with the following comment posted on the jQuery page:

> Have to agree with @anonymous: jQuery works around a wide variety of
>   browser inconsistencies, that's probably about half its purpose (the
>   other half being simplifying complex operations). This is a classic
>   browser inconsistency: Chrome and Firefox support  CORS via
>   XMLHttpRequest; IE instead uses XDomainRequest. It makes no more sense
>   for this to be a plug-in than it would for (say) handling IE's broken
>   getAttribute function being a plug-in. Recommend reopening and
>   scheduling for 1.6.1 or 1.6.2 (especially as jQuery now has the jqXHR
>   concept).

Comment: Thanks! *(That was my comment. It sounded familiar and then suddenly I realized...)* :-)

Comment: Interesting. I do have to agree with [**comment 43**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283#comment:43) on the bug-thread. If XDR in IE is so fragile and has so many issues in it's own right, would it be wise for jQuery to even try to work with it, taking responsibility for the native XDR issues/failures? Would it not make more sense in that case for a separate plug-in to work with it instead of making it part of jQuery Core? It does sound risky given the nature of the above mentioned issues.

Comment: Yes, I got to reading more and it seems that cors implementation in IE 8 and 9 is too weak to be taken serious. So if you want to support the IE 7 and 8 browsers it might be a better idea to stick with JSONP There might be cases where you could get away with the limited support but the comment of IE 8 breaking down completely when InPrivate browsing is set worries me.

Comment: A warning in the documentation would be nice though. For anyone curious to use cors should re consider if they plan to support IE 9 and below.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason jQuery chose not to support IE 8/9 XDomainRequest is that full support of CORS is not possible on those browsers.  For example, you can't sent custom headers with XDomainRequest, and the request type is always going to be text/plain.

For many applications, those limitations don't matter. I've found that including this library allows me to support CORS on IE 8/9 not just with jQuery, but also with AngularJS and other frameworks:

https://github.com/intuit/xhr-xdr-adapter/blob/master/src/xhr-xdr-adapter.js

The example in the question above should work fine if you include the xhr-xdr-adapter first.