# cross domain with jsonp and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, internet-explorer-10

I am doing a cross-domain request from `site1.com` to `site2.com` (both maintained by me)

This is the jquery code on site1.com :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://site2.com/test/carrousel.cfm',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true, 
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data, status) {
           alert(data);}
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('error');
        }
    });
```

I can see the request coming in with status 200 in the debugger. The response body
also contains the string that I'm sending from the server. That string is: `"okay"`

Strange enough, the error handler is always fired and I can't access the data. 
I'm sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers via the server too (I came across some posts asking to do this)

I also get a script error saying 'OKAY' is undefined. 'OKAY' is the string I get as a reply from the server. How come this is happening? And  How can I get this cross domain request to succeed?

I'm using JQUERY 1.10.2 & IE 10

As you can see I'm also using jsonp & the right parameters as defined in the jquery documentation to perform cross domain requests

Comment: you are saying the the response is of type `jsonp` but your response is a string `okay` which is invalid, `jsonp` response should be of format `somemethod(data)`. Since your server is sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers... change the datatype to `text` and try

Comment: *The response body also contains the string that I'm sending from the server. That string is: "okay"* `"okay"` is not valid jsonp. the cross-domain headers aren't needed for jsonp requests.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: setting the type to text still fires the errorhandle

Comment: **I wrote an answer related to this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)** – _the last one, supports https_

Answer (score 1):

You should try Ajax-cross-origin a jQuery plugin.

http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

You will be able to use ajax cross domain with no limitation!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple JSONP excahnge:

1. The client makes a `<script src="target.js?arg=foo">` tag
2. The server gets the request for `target.js`.
3. The PHP server-side body of `target.js` is `clientFunction("$_GET['arg']")`
4. The client gets back a script: `clientFunction("foo")`
5. The client executes the script, which causes the client-side function `clientFunction` to run, with the argument `"foo"`.

The obvious takeaway here is: JSONP responses **are scripts**. If your client asks for a JSONP response, it is asking *for a script*. The content "`okay`" is therefore being treated as a script, but `okay` hasn't been declared as a valid identifier in your client scripting environment, so it causes an error. (In my example above, we assume that `clientFunction` has been declared client-side before the exchange takes place.)

If you have control over the server and can serve CORS headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, then you don't need JSONP. Just make a normal Ajax request.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you want to support IE<10, you'll need to add support for CORS to jQuery so that it will work in IE8+. it will not work in IE7 regardless as it doesn't support CORS.

Comment: Namely, add IE8+ support by using a plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688703/is-there-a-jquery-solution-that-uses-cors-when-available-and-falls-back-to-xdoma

Comment: It's not letting me do normal ajax requests.. It still fires the error handle

Comment: What I did now was format my string on the server like this:
jsonpres = 'OKAY';

and on the client side, in the error handle, I can do console.log(jsonpres);

But this is not a nice solution at all..